# React: have component receive props or state, or generate an id, before mixin code is run

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my React component, I would like to be able to pass a mixin a dynamic value, either received from the component's props or state, or from a function that the component runs before it executes the mixin. Is this possible?

Basically, I want to do something along the lines of:

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */
var React = require('react');
var MyMixin = require('./myMixin').MyMixin;

var Test = React.createClass({
  mixins: [MyMixin.wantsToKnowTheTestId(this.props.id)],
  propTypes: {
    id: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired
  },
  render: function() {
    return (<h1>My id is: {this.props.id}</h1>);
  }
});

module.exports = {Test: Test};
```

Of course, when I run the above I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined` since `this.props` is not defined yet when the mixin runs.

**Is this, or anything like it, possible?**

Comment: The mixin just becomes part of the class, so you can't do what you're trying. The `this` would be the `window` for example if just executed in the browser.  What are you trying to accomplish? Mixins don't have much of a future as is in react.

Comment: @WiredPrairie I'm using Reflux and would like to be able to give [Reflux.connect](https://github.com/spoike/refluxjs#using-refluxconnect) the id of the component.

Comment: Like others have said, this is simply not possible because the call to Reflux.connect happens long before any props are available. And the call only happens once, whereas your component can be created multiple times with different props. Could you expand on your use case? Perhaps there's a better way to go about solving it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can think of code inside a mixin as simply getting copied into your component, so what you're thinking of wouldn't work.

Depending on what the method inside your mixin is doing, you could consider using a lifecycle method inside your mixin that will execute after the component is initialized (and therefore once this.props is defined).

So your mixin would look like

```
var MyMixin = {
  wantsToKnowTheTestId: function(id) { ... },

  componentDidMount: function() {
    this.wantsToKnowTheTestId(this.props.id);
  }

}
```

And your component would simply include this mixin

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */
var React = require('react');
var MyMixin = require('./myMixin').MyMixin;

var Test = React.createClass({
  mixins: [MyMixin],
  propTypes: {
    id: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired
  },
  render: function() {
    return (<h1>My id is: {this.props.id}</h1>);
  }
});

module.exports = {Test: Test};
```

Comment: This seems like a good idea. I'll leave answers open for a bit but otherwise I'll accept this. Question: If I have the same lifecycle function in both a mixin and the component itself, will they both fire or will one override the other?

Comment: @MatthewHerbst React will do the "right thing;" for example, for `componentDidMount`, they'll both run. For `getInitialState`, React will merge the objects from each.

Comment: The mixin's lifecycle methods are indeed the answer. More on that in the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#mixins). The last paragraph in the mixins section also states BinaryMuse's answer.

Comment: @smhg Thanks for linking to the docs. The reference to mixins helped.

Comment: @BinaryMuse thanks for that. To build on it though, how does React determine which to run first? I imagine this could lead to problems sometimes

Comment: @BinaryMuse never mind. From the docs :) `Methods defined on mixins run in the order mixins were listed, followed by a method call on the component.`